# Trying to replace part of a string starts with /x2D

Tags: java, jmeter

In JMeter, I used a Regular Expression Extractor to extract part of an HTML response. I then passed that to a BeanShell Post Processor. However, having trouble replacing \x2D to -. Is there a way to do this or perhaps do I need to extract the response as

```
 String yourvar = vars.get("accessToken");
 String  anotherVar = yourvar.replace("data.access_token = '","");
 String  finalAccessToken = anotherVar.replace("\x2D","-");
 vars.put("finalAccessToken",finalAccessToken);
```

It is not liking the "\x2D" part. It works if I find \x2D but the original string only has .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is recommended to use JMeter's built-in test elements where possible. In particular your case you might be interested in [__strReplace() custom JMeter Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strReplacesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-4-0-font-sup)

   - Install Custom JMeter Functions bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

     [image]
   - Use the following expression to make the replacement:

     ```
     ${__strReplace(${anotherVar},\\\x2D,-,)}
     ```

     [image]
2. If you want to go for scripting - make sure to use [JSR223 PostProcessor and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting). Be aware that you will still need to [escape backslash with another backslash](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-dotnet-escape.html) like:

   ```
   String  finalAccessToken = anotherVar.replace("\\x2D","-");
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your `target` `String` parameter.

```
final String finalAccessToken = anotherVar.replace("\\x2D", "-");
```

If it's not what you're asking for, add more info to the question. That's all what I was able to understand.